SSRS how to write a formula like Crystal with a variable in - in an SSRS expression
I wonder if you can help me - In Crystal we have loads of formulas that use variables like when using whileprinting records for example
NumberVar v := abs({@Quantity_l} - truncate({@Quantity_l})); // abs required for negatives
StringVar x := totext(v,4); // allow upto 4 dp
if x[3 to 6] = '0000' then
'' // don't show the decimal point !!
else if x[4 to 6] = '000' then
x[2 to 3]
else if x[5 to 6] = '00' then
x[2 to 4]
else if x[6] = '0' then
x[2 to 5]
else
x[2 to 6]
Is there a way to do this in SSRS? I can see you can add variables to the report but cant see how you could replicate the above? I am trying to get rid of any trailing zeros on the right side of a quantity just for reference.
Many many thanks for any help at all
Kind regards Dawn
I have tried creating a variable in SSRS but it doesnt work the same as in Crystal

Maybe some answers here?

You could either put it in a custom function or expression.

Public Function


To call this from a textbox use the following format =CodeFormatQuantity(Fields!Quantity.Value)
    Public Function FormatQuantity(ByVal quantity As Double) As String
        Dim v As Double = Math.Abs(quantity - Math.Floor(quantity)) ' Absolute value of fractional part
        Dim x As String = v.ToString("0.0000") ' Convert to string with 4 decimal places

        If x.Substring(3, 4) = "0000" Then
            Return "" ' No decimal point
        ElseIf x.Substring(4, 3) = "000" Then
            Return x.Substring(1, 2) ' Return first two digits after the decimal point
        ElseIf x.Substring(5, 2) = "00" Then
            Return x.Substring(1, 3) ' Return first three digits after the decimal point
        ElseIf x.Substring(6, 1) = "0" Then
            Return x.Substring(1, 4) ' Return first four digits after the decimal point
        Else
            Return x.Substring(1, 5) ' Return full decimal part (up to 4 digits)
        End If
    End Function


Expression
 =IIF(
     Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)) = 0, 
     "0", 
     IIF(
         Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 4, 4) = "0000", 
         "", 
         IIF(
             Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 5, 3) = "000", 
             Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 2, 2),
             IIF(
                 Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 6, 2) = "00", 
                 Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 2, 3),
                 IIF(
                     Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 7, 1) = "0",
                     Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 2, 4),
                     Mid(Format(Abs(Fields!Quantity_l.Value - Int(Fields!Quantity_l.Value)), "0.0000"), 2, 5)
                 )
             )
         )
     )
 )




Thank you so much @aduguid!! I will give this a try - very very much appreciated for all of your comments and time! Thank you
